# SQLite - How to fix syntax error (code 1)

Tags: android, sqlite

Inside of my Input.java file I have

```
public class Input {

    private int _id;
    private String _username;

    public Input(){

    }

    public Input(String username){
        this._username = username;
    }

    public void set_id(int _id) {
        this._id = _id;
    }

    public void set_username(String _username) {
        this._username = _username;
    }

    public int get_id() {
        return _id;
    }

    public String get_username() {
        return _username;
    }
}
```

and inside of my DBHandler.java

```
public class DBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "input.db";
    public static final String TABLE_INPUT = "input";
    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_USERNAME = "username";

public DBHandler(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_INPUT + "(" +
            COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT " +
            COLUMN_USERNAME +  " TEXT " +
            ");";
    db.execSQL(query);
}
```

Whenever I try to execute this, I get the error:

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "username": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE input(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT username TEXT );
```

What exactly am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a comma before username:

```
" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT<missing comma here> "
```

Corrected code below:

```
 String query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_INPUT + "(" +
            COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            COLUMN_USERNAME +  " TEXT " +
            ");";
```

Comment: You are welcome, you can mark it answered so that helps others in the future